# What characters are in my python identation sections in vim?

Tags: python, indentation, vim

I have this in my vimrc.

```
set listchars=trail:.,tab:>-,eol:$
set nolist
noremap <leader>i :set list!<CR> " Toggle invisible chars
```

When I'm programming in Python and I run `<leader>i`, my identation doesn't show any characters, since it isn't trailing whitespace, neither tabs.

Now, I'm wondering: what character exactly are in my identation if they arent whitespace, or tabs?

I'm asking this because I'm planning to ignore whitespace in vimdiff, but isn't doing this going to be a problem when editing python files, where whitespace is relevant?

Comment: *You* should know - after all, you typed it. I guess its spaces. Yes, that's whitespace, but not trailing if used for indentation.

Comment: @delnan: I open files created by other people. If I use listchars=nbsp:% doesn't show anythint either, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what other character would it be? Spaces are invisible, tabs would show up with `>----` as necessary, and I've never seen a vertical tab included in a file before, but I can't imagine it would make for very good indentation in a Python program. What other whitespace characters could it be?

Comment: @sarnold: I've update my question with more info, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation is spaces.  Trailing whitespace is whitespace with nothing but a newline after it.  Indentation obviously has code after it, thus no list char.

In regards to your edit, you have a few options.

- Don't make vimdiff ignore whitespace for python files by setting `diffopt` with an `autocmd FileType python`.
- Indent your code using tabs (`set noexpandtab` for python files), and use `set list` when diffing files to compare indentation.  This is far less desirable because vim won't highlight and point out the differences in indentation for you.

There may be more options, but those are the two I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @Somebody - not sure if you get notices on edits but I've updated with my suggestions. (Can you let me know if you did get a notice for the edit so I know for future reference?)

Comment: Your comment appears at the "Stackexchange" bar at the top, but I didn't receive a "notice" beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at a typical source file with a hex editor, or use Python:

```
python -c "print repr(open('yourfile.py', 'rb').read(1024))"
```

will print the first 1Kb of your file unambiguously.